# R trouble with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I am a beginner to R and I am doing some project and want some help regrading that. Here I will give input as **pollutantmean(, "nitrate", 70:72)** and the output should contain the mean of all nitrate values from 70, 71 and 72 files. I have file names as 001.csv, 002.csv.. etc. So I used sprintf function to get it
That is just an example. I had over 300 files and I want to store the output from each for loop processing into a vector and take mean of it and display it. But I cann't get the  **mean** of it.

```
pollutantmean <- function(dir, pollutant, id) {
            dir <- getwd()
            cases <- NULL
            for(i in id){
                    csvfile <- sprintf("%03d.csv", as.numeric(i))
                    filepath <- file.path(paste(dir,"specdata",csvfile, sep="/"))
                    foo <- read.csv(filepath)
                    foo
                    if (pollutant == "sulfate") {                                
                            jar <- (foo$sulfate)
                    } else if (pollutant == "nitrate") {
                            jar <- (foo$nitrate)
                    }
                    cases[i] <- jar
            }
            foo1 <- mean(cases, na.rm=TRUE)
            print(foo1)    
    }
```

Comment: What can't you get? The files, the mean, ...?

Comment: First, you can remove dir as an argument : you replace the value by `getwd()` at the beginning. The in file.path, no need to paste value, juste use `file.path(dir,'specdata,'csvfile')`. Maybe case is a list ? if so, initialize like this `case <- list()`. To interrupt a function a explore its environment, put a `browser()` command, then check all variables.

Comment: You are trying to get the mean based on cases, but you overwrite your cases in your for loop every time on the first line.

Comment: @Simon so how to avoid overwriting..

Comment: by not overwriting it on the first line of the loop? I have to say I did this one quite differently, I just merged the dataframes.

Comment: @SimonVerhoeven I changed the code as u said. I initiated cases above the for loop. Eventhough I cannt get the mean. Any way thnx for the help

Answer (score 0):

This question is a homework question for the Johns Hopkins University R Programming course on Coursera. Since it's a homework assignment, we can't give you a complete answer, i.e. the typical Stackoverflow.com answer that shows working code.

That said, I'll provide enough information for you to fix the function on your own.  The code fails because `cases[i] <- jar` tries to set a single element (e.g id == 70), or `cases[70]` to a vector, `jar` that has multiple elements.

Given the way you've written the code, consider using the combine function `c()` to combine the `cases` vector with the `jar` vector instead of `cases[i] <- jar`.